# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setValues' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined. (react / create-react-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am having **TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setValues' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.** error and I am not sure why. I have a piece of code from App.js:

```
import { DataProvider, useData } from "./DataContext";

function App({ ...rest }) {

  const { setValues, data } = useData();

...
```

and the DataContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const DataContext = createContext();

export const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const setValues = (values) => {
    setData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      ...values
    }));
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{ data, setValues }}>
      {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useData = () => useContext(DataContext);
```

Here is the CodeSandBox link for the complete codes:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-app-test-wvmlp?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: looks that you are accessing the hook reading che context in the same component where you inject the context provider, so the comtext is noy available there. first wrap a componeny with yhe provider, then inside the wrapped component, call the hooks for reading from the context

Comment: @quirimmo Please fix your typos

Comment: @CodeApprentice i am by phone but i hope the idea is clear, he is accessing the context in the App, where most probably it will inject it. so he is accessing a context not available yet. The value of context is undefined, you are accessing a prop (setValue) of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sandbox your not using the DataProvider maybe in your Index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { DataProvider} from "./DataContext";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
   <DataProvider>
    <App />
   </DataProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Comment: bingo, that' s the issue plus one by me

Comment: trying to say the same through comments since long

Comment: Thank you @quirimmo imy bad I just looked at the sandbox

Comment: haha, i didn't read his code, just imagine it. So maybe that's it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the missing code but it is giving another undefined error:  Cannot read property 'textField' of undefined

Comment: this is another problem @JasonLex but I don't understand why you use yup and react-hook-form?

Comment: Hi Daphaz, I was thinking of using yup to parse form values and validations later...

Comment: ok see [this](https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/#CustomHookwithResolver) I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will read that and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Your useContext is wired with `DataContext` which takes initial data from `{{ data, setValues }}`.

Therefore when you use it in consumer `App`, it needs to be

const { data, setValues } = useData();

This might be the first typo. But maybe this is not where the problem is.

Have you tried to fire `DataProvider` as in one part of your app first.

```
  <DataProvider>
     <App>
        <YOURCOMPONENT />
     </App>
  </DataProvider>
  <DataProvider>
     <App2 />
  </DataProvider>
```

I can see this is what the author want you to use, and then inside your component, use `useData`.

Comment: if this was the case, although the typo, he would have "setValues is not a function" . having the cannot access a prop of undefined means that the object he destructures is undefined, so the check for the typos does not even happen yet

Comment: you might be right,  {} order doesn't matter. Let me think about it.

Comment: check my comment, even cause i do not care about points. he is simply reading a context not available because he calls the hooks in the same App component which will inject the context

Comment: maybe he forget the `Provider` as you mentioned, but maybe the `Provider` has fired in other parts of the app. Because this piece is very ambitious.

Comment: nope cause there is the Import of the provider in the App.tsx and there is the sandbox :)